# moviepy render comes out as trash after first clip

Tags: python, moviepy

So im trying to concatenate the clips but after the first clip it stops working. Does anyone know how to fix this? Is this a bug or something? because I really cannot figure this out

here is my code

```
from moviepy.editor import*

#intro video
intro = VideoFileClip(r"assets\intro-CWH.mp4")

#intro audio
#introAudio = AudioFileClip(r"assets\Youtube Branding\gottagobaldsoundeffect.mp3")

#subscribe clip
subscribeScreen = ImageClip(r"assets\subscreens\subscreen-1.jpg", duration=4.5)

#main clips
clip1 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\1.mp4")
clip2 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\2.mp4")
clip3 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\3.mp4")
clip4 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\4.mp4")
clip5 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\5.mp4")
clip6 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\6.mp4")
clip7 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\7.mp4")
clip8 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\8.mp4")
clip9 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\9.mp4")
clip10 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\10.mp4")
clip11 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\11.mp4")
clip12 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\12.mp4")
clip13 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\13.mp4")
clip14 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\14.mp4")
clip15 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\15.mp4")
clip16 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\16.mp4")
clip17 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\17.mp4")
clip18 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\18.mp4")
clip19 = VideoFileClip(r"assets\temp\19.mp4")

#outro
outro = VideoFileClip(r"assets\Youtube Branding\Outro's\pinkvynil.mov").subclip(0, 10)

fullArray = [clip1, intro, clip2, clip3, clip4, clip5, subscribeScreen, clip6, clip7, 
clip8, clip9, clip10, clip11, clip12, clip13, clip14, clip15, clip16, clip17, clip18, 
clip19]
fullVideo = concatenate_videoclips(fullArray)

#render
fullVideo.write_videofile("testvideo.mp4", fps=30)
```

Comment: Do you get errors? Have a traceback?

Comment: No, the terminal gives no errors.

Comment: Moviepy - Building video testvideo.mp4.
Moviepy - Writing video testvideo.mp4

Moviepy - Done !
Moviepy - video ready testvideo.mp4

Comment: Okay - does the `testvideo.mp4` file you create only have the first clip? Or does it have everything but it's all broken/scrambled/etc.?

Comment: first clip if normal but after the first clip its all scrambled

Answer (score 1):

because the video's are in different sizes you need to add the method compose

```
fullVideo = concatenate_videoclips(fullArray, method="compose")
```